# Junit 5 Assertions.fail() can not infer type in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, junit5

When I attempt to use JUnit 5 Assertions.fail in my Kotlin tests I get a compilation failure because parameter V can not be inferred:

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.fail
internal class MyTests {
   @Test
   fun simpleTest() {
     fail("Does not compile") 
   }
}
```

Of course a simple solution to this problem is:

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.fail
internal class MyTests {
   @Test
   fun simpleTest() {
     val result: Any = fail("Compiles") 
   }
}
```

However I do not wish to have to create an unused value in my code. Is there a way to define the type without having to declare a val? Also why does this happen in Kotlin? Java has no such problem with generics:

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.fail;
class MyJavaTests {
    @Test
    public void simpleTest() {
        fail("Compiles);
    }
}
```

EDIT: I discovered immediately after posting the question that the solution is to parameterize the call:

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.fail
internal class MyTests {
   @Test
   fun simpleTest() {
     fail<Any>("Does not compile") 
   }
 }
```

However still willing to accept an answer that can explain why I need to do this in kotlin.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Please see this issue: https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/issues/1209

It seems that this is already fixed in the junit-jupiter-api **Assertions.kt file** as a top-level function in org.junit.jupiter.api package.

Import the **org.junit.jupiter.api.fail** and not the org.junit.jupiter.api.**Assertions**.fail

Comment: Thanks for linking the issue. My version is 5.1.1. It is fixed in this one as well, your second link revealed the real problem. Wrong import. should have been org.junit.jupiter.api.fail . If you amend I will accept the answer